# Multiplayer turn based game architecture questions

Tags: java, mysql, webserver, multiplayer

I'm working on creating a 2D game for fun to learn some of the ins and outs of multiplayer gaming. The game itself will pit two players' armies against each other in a strategic turn based battle. I am developing it as a standalone desktop client (then maybe a phone app eventually).

I am writing the game in Java and I am not trusting the client, so I am taking security into account. The players will have an personal account with their army lists and stuff that will live on the server as well.  Additionally, I plan on using mySQL to store this sort of data on the server.

I'm not really sure how to implement this, however. Do I use something like a webserver? This seems wrong, but I don't know what technologies to use for a Java front end and backend where the client is untrusted.  Note that I'm not looking for a debate about the best way to do this, I just need to know the concepts, maybe some example technologies, and maybe a link to a tutorial.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Misclicked that, thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to use SQL for it? A simple server which handles TCP connection for chat and UDP connection for player actions would be more like that what you need.

Comment: I'll tell you this - libgdx has immeasurably helped me with my android development. You can develop for desktop and device at the same time seamlessly. They have a good community that can definitely give some pointers for security. I myself haven't hit that point in any of my apps, but it's a very strong framework and they have almost positively taken it into consideration. It may not help if you're well along in development, but if you're just starting I strongly suggest you check it out and run some examples. You will be surprised how fast you can develop with it.

Comment: The database will hold data about the players accounts.  They will be able build different army lists and it will store their basic account info.  A lot of this is for learning.  @KaiQing I actually am using libgdx.  I guess I just don't know how to use the TCP/UDP stuff.

Comment: Heh, well cool then. post what you learn as I will eventually want to know the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are planning for this to be a browser game, I don't think that using a webserver would be the best idea.

Sockets may be the answer you are looking for, with them you could create your own communication protocol that doesn't trust the client.

Your server will need to use a server socket and accept multiple clients.

You can also use [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for the client UI.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) is the default java Sockets tutorial.

For example your protocol could include the following commands:
(Client to Server) Move(UnitGroup, Point) - tells the server you want to move a group to a point, the server then performs the calculations to determine what time it will take for the units to arrive and start moving them there.

(Server to Client) PositionUpdated(UnitGroup, Point) - tells the client that a group moved somewhere and may need to be updated in the display

If you publish your protocol, players could even make their own clients to view the game as they wish.  Your server would keep it fair by only giving the clients the things that they should 'see'.

I have no idea how this might affect latency though.

Comment: Awesome, I think this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a bit to Psetmaj's helpful answer:

Your game client and game server are going to deal with the structures (lists, etc) you use in a very Java-centric way.  The part you're not yet experience in is going to be figuring out how to package up these commands and structures for transport in TCP or UDP and then unpacking them at the other end.  This is called "marshalling" (when you pack the payload) and "de-marshalling" (when you unpack it and turn it back into something Java can understand).  In fact, the "hard" part about it is that it is very tedious and needs to happen for every different message that goes back or forth.

My advice is to work on a library of helper functions, as you proceed, that is responsible for transforming the structures you use into and out of the representation they will have when you send and receive them across a network.  That representation can be text-based, like AJAX or binary-based, like Java's RMI, whichever you decide to try.

Comment: Java serialization does all of that for you.  Start with Java serialization, then change your approach if that becomes a problem (possible reasons:  performance, cross-language compatibility, bandwidth).

Comment: Isn't there some library I can use that abstracts this away rather than writing my own helper functions? (I don't enjoy reinventing the wheel).

Comment: There are, and they are not hard to find by searching.  But my answer is useful if you really want to learn the ins and outs of multiplayer gaming for yourself.  If you want to study someone else's implementation, on the other hand, [Firebase](http://www.cubeia.org/index.php/firebase) is open source and has many features.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I shall investigate into this further.